# What is the equivalent to $ when working with atomic vectors?

Tags: r

I made a sample of a dataset named `test_data`. I want to find the missing values in the column named `relat_age` which is a `factor`.

The code I used is:

```
sum(test_data$relat_age=="")
```

Furthermore, I tried to find the average age using column `Age_last_bday`, an `integer` using

```
mean(test_data$Age_last_bday)
```

Both returned error

> $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.

Comment: Hi. Can you edit your question with the results of `dput(head(test_data, 10))` please. This will allow us to see the structire of your data. (ps its often useful to have missing data coded as `NA` rather than `""` -- an empty string. Additionally it is often useful to convert empty strings to `NA` when readin gin the data e.g. `read.table` has an `na.strings` argument)

Comment: The message is saying that `test_data` is not a dataframe or similar, it's either a simple vector, or maybe a matrix.  Use `test_data[, "relat_age"] == ""` to look at a column of a matrix. (This syntax also works for dataframes.)  If it's a simple vector, then it doesn't make any sense to select a column, because it doesn't have columns.

Comment: I voted to close the question down. Should the OP comply with the suggestions by @user20650, I may review the close vote.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

The $ operator is just fine.  The problem is that you must tell `sum` and `mean` that you want to ignore the missing values.  Use

```
sum(test_data$relat_age=="", na.rm = TRUE)
```

and

```
mean(test_data$Age_last_bday, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would lead to a different issue, i.e. a result of `NA` rather than the reported error.

Comment: Yeah the above code doesn't work but i found a code that does. Would you like me to share it or are you guys uninterested.

Comment: You should modify your question first as suggested by @user20650, then feel free to answer it.  That'll be the best way to help the next person to come along with the same issue.